# Immunity Debugger - Error 193 during loading a file

Tags: debugging, error-code

When I try to load `beep.sys` into Immunity Debugger, it creates a directory named **_krndrvbk** in the folder:

`C:\Users\k1rk1r\AppData\Roaming\Immunity Debugger`.

The whole path then looks like:

`C:\Users\k1rk1r\AppData\Roaming\Immunity Debugger\_krndrvbk\beep.sys`

I have found out that the Error code **193** means that I have a whitespace in the path. So, the folder **"Immunity Debugger"** must be responsible for that.

But I did not create it. The whole path/folders are created by the debugger.

Does somebody know how to configure Immunity Debugger to not create such a folder or to use the correct path?